# Compare mysql array to select statement in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have no clue is this is possible, but here's what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a simple php statement:

```
$ID = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['ID']));

$sqlApp = "SELECT * from apps WHERE appID = ".$ID;
$resultApp = mysql_query($sqlApp);
$rowApp = mysql_fetch_array($resultApp);

$fileName = $rowApp['fileName'];
```

Say my ID number is 1 and the fileName is "mobi."

I want to check my fileName against another fileName in this query.

```
SELECT fileName, count(appId) as ct
FROM `apps`
GROUP BY filename
HAVING ct<2
```

If my fileName "mobi" is found in this query, then I want to echo that it has no duplicates. Is there a way to compare my php variable to a query? If this is not possible, what's another way I could try to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Why not `select count(*) where fileName = $filename`? If it is >1 you have a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this query:

```
$query = "select * from
(
SELECT fileName, count(appId) as ct
FROM apps
GROUP BY filename
HAVING ct<2
)cs
where cs.fileName = 
(SELECT fileName from apps WHERE appID = ".$ID.")";
```

Comment: so if I understand your code correctly, this will only print out a fileName if it has no duplicates?

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you know the file name why not just do:  select count(*) from apps where filename = $filename

And if you want to make sure that filename is never duplicated then create a unique index on it.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with your SQL...

```
$sqlApp = "SELECT fileName, count(appId) as ct FROM `apps` WHERE fileName = '' GROUP BY filename HAVING ct<2";
$resultApp = mysql_query($sqlApp);
$has_duplicates = false;
while ( $rowApp = mysql_fetch_array($resultApp) ) {
    $has_duplicates = true;
}
```

Simply run your query then assign 'true' to a variable if the query has results.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it that way:

```
$id = (isset($_POST['ID']) ? intval($_POST['id']) : 0);

$mysqli = new mysqli ('host', 'db_user', 'db_pwd', 'db_name');
$sql = 'SELECT fileName from apps WHERE appID = ?';
$fileName = '';
if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $statement->bind_param('i', $id);
    $statement->execute();
    if ($result = $statement->get_result()) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $fileName = $row['fileName'];
        $result->free();
    }
    $statement->close();
}
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(fileName) AS count
                FROM   apps
                WHERE  fileName = ?';
$count = 0;
if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $statement->bind_param('s', $fileName);
    $statement->execute();
    if ($result = $statement->get_result()) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $count = $row['count'];
        $result->free();
    }
    $statement->close();
}
$mysqli->close();

if ($count == 1) {
    echo 'The file '.$fileName.' has no duplicates';
}
```